# Valor undefined en el formulario dependiente del div Padre

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Quisiera saber por qué me muestra un valor indefinido cuando ejecuto mi formulario. Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
$(".devolucion-denegar").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let padre = $(this);

    let idtramite = padre.find(".idtramite").val();
    let num_doct = padre.find(".numdoct").val();
    let tipo_doct = padre.find(".tipodoc").val();
        
    var datosdene = new FormData();
    datosdene.append("idtramite", idtramite);
    datosdene.append("num_doct", num_doct);
    datosdene.append("tipo_doct", tipo_doct);

    console.log(idtramite, num_doct, tipo_doct);
})
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal devolucion-denegar mt-3" method="post">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" name="frmid" class="idtramite" value="1" required="required" />

        <input type="text" name="frmndocument" class="numdoct" value="a12" required="required" />

        <input type="text" name="frmtipo" class="tipodoc" value="Oficio" required="required" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control detalledenegacion" name="frmcorregir" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Denegar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

No entiendo por qué me sale indefinido, ya que cuando lo he probado en otra plataforma me funciona bien, es decir la lógica.

Comment: Hice unos ajustes a su código para que corriera aquí (aún no han aceptado mis cambios) y funciona bien, el resultado no es undefined. Los cambios son simples, añadí JQuery y un texto al textarea. ¿Pudiera usted explicar mejor el contexto en el que falla su código?

Comment: Revertí la edición porque en ella se modificaba el código del autor. Se puede formatear el código, pero no se debe modificar. No debió estar aprobado, a menos, que haya sido por el autor, pero eso, invalidaría el objetivo de la pregunta porque solucionaría el error en un área que no corresponde.